# smarty displaying only first character from foreach

Tags: php, mysql, smarty, whmcs

I am just starting to use Smarty templates and have this very simple query:

```
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT `name`, `min_price` FROM `tblproductgroups` WHERE `hidden` != 'on' ORDER BY `order` ASC");
   $data = mysql_fetch_array($result);
   $ca->assign('products', $data);
```

And tempate file is like this:

```
{foreach from=$products key=key item=product}

{$product.name} - {$product.id}<br/>

{/foreach}
```

And the outcome comes out like this:

```
V - V
V - V
6 - 6
6 - 6
```

V is the first character for VPS (name) and 6 is the first character of price.
How can I make Smarty to display the full information?

Comment: `mysql_fetch_array` will only get the first element. You need to do something like `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ... }`

Comment: So I should assign the 'products' variable in the while() loop?

Comment: Okay, fixed this by changing PHP

       while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result))
     $assign[] = $data;
    
        $ca->assign('products', $assign);

Thanks for the tip @Amal Murali

Comment: You're welcome. You don't need two loops to do this simple task though.

Comment: Sorry, but how is it possible to do this with one loop?