# Grabbing certain values from an array in Smarty

Tags: php, arrays, smarty, smarty3, smarty2

I have been trying this for hours, If it was just PHP I would be done by now but this requires Smarty 3 so things are a little different. I am having difficulty grabbing specific keys plural from an Array. The Array looks like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [client] => Jane Doe
            [email] => jane@doe.com
        )
   [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [client] => John Doe
            [email] => john@doe.com
        )
   [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [client] => Jim Doe
            [email] => jim@doe.com
        )
```

I can access this using PHP just fine, the Smarty is tripping me up, the files are two

- clients.php
- clients.tpl <- smarty

I assign the array in the .php file with the following

```
$totalEntries = $results['products']['product'];
$ca->assign('innerArray', $totalEntries);
```

The `$results['products']['product']` is what outputs the array seen above.

Now in the **.tpl** file, I have the following

```
  <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
   {foreach $innerArray as $results} 
    {foreach from=$results.client item=label}
    <option value="{$label}">{$label}</option>
    {/foreach}
  {/foreach}
  </select>
```

This works to output to the dropdown

- Jane Doe
- John Doe
- Jim Doe

I got that part right, and I have been looking all over the internet to figure this out. My plan was to introduce into the drop down something like

- Jane Doe - jane@doe.com
- John Doe - john@doe.com
- Jim Doe - jim@doe.com

However when I attempt this using something like the following where i remove the **.client** part of the **from=**

```
  <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
   {foreach $innerArray as $results} 
    {foreach from=$results item=label}
    <option value="{$label.client}">{$label.client} - {$label.email}</option>
    {/foreach}
  {/foreach}
  </select>
```

I am met with a list that looks like this

- 1 - 1
- J - J
- j - j
- 2 - 2
- J - J
- j - j
- 3 - 3
- J - J
- j - j

I realize this is basically the first letters and numbers, but I see variety of examples online showing that I can take from the array what I need, but when I try **$label.client - $label.email** It won't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19276200/smarty-displaying-only-first-character-from-foreach

Comment: That sounds like my issue but not really as I use WHMCS and I am not fetching anything using personal database connection, I am getting already made variables by WHMCS such as $userid and so on. However I arrived at my solution just before the answer came to it after hours of work, but his solution ended up being so much cleaner I dumped mine out the window :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not like the way you did, but using {section} will do:

```
<select class="form-control" id="sel1">
{section name=seq loop=$innerArray}
  <option value="{$innerArray[seq].id}">{$innerArray[seq].client} - $innerArray[seq].email}</option>
{/section}
</select>
```

Comment: Such a beautiful solution.. Thank you so much!, I was almost there but mine was so crummy.. 

   {foreach $innerArray as $results} 
    {foreach from=$results key=key item=label}
    {if $key == "client"}
    <option value="{$results.client} - {$results.email}">{$results.client} - {$results.email}</option>
    {/if}
    {/foreach}
  {/foreach}

Comment: Your version, is so clean! mine spit out 100 results until I jammed a "if key" to stop it at certain amount of results.. Accepted hands down.

Answer (score 1):

Smarty 3 lets you to use php-style "foreach" but mantains the old Smarty 2 style, so you can simply do the following:

```
{foreach $arr as $idx => $person}
  <option value="{$person.client}">{$person.client} - {$person.email}</option>
{/foreach}
```

Also, as per the Smarty 3 manual:

> The {foreach} loop can do everything a {section} loop can do, and has a simpler and easier syntax. It is usually preferred over the {section} loop.